# What is the most efficient operator to compare any two items?

Tags: type-conversion, comparison, raku

Frequently I need to convert data from one type to another and then compare them. Some operators will convert to specific types first and this conversion may cause loss of efficiency. For instance, I may have

```
my $a, $b = 0, "foo"; # initial value
$a = (3,4,5).Set;     # re-assign value
$b = open "dataFile"; # re-assign value

if $a eq $b { say "okay"; } # convert to string
if $a == 5 { say "yes"; }   # convert to number
if $a == $b {} # error, Cannot resolve caller Numeric(IO::Handle:D: );
```

The operators "eq" and "==" will convert data to the digestible types first and may slow things down. Will the operators "eqv" and "===" skip converting data types and be more efficient if data to be compared cannot be known in advance (i.e., you absolutely have no clue what you are going to get in advance)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `===` and `eqv` first check whether the operands are of the same type, and will return `False` if they are not.  So at that stage, there is no real difference between them.

The `a === b` operator is really short for `a.WHICH eq b.WHICH`.  So it would call the `.WHICH` method on the operands, which could be expensive if an operand is something like a really large `Buf`.

The `a eqv b` operator is more complicated in that it has special cased many object comparisons, so in general you cannot say much about it.

In other words: YMMV.  And if you're really interested in performance, benchmark!  And be prepared to adapt your code if another way of solving the problem proves more performant.

Answer (score 9):

It's not quite clear to me from the question if you actually *want* the conversions to happen or not.

Operators like `==` and `eq` are really calls to `multi` `sub`s with names like `infix:<==>`, and there are many candidates. For example, there's one for `(Int, Int)`, which is selected if we're comparing two `Int`s. In that case, it knows that it doesn't need to coerce, and will just do the integer comparison.

The `eqv` and `===` operators will not coerce; the first thing they do is to check that the values have the same type, and if they don't, they go no further. Make sure to use the correct one depending of if you want snapshot semantics (`eqv`) or reference semantics (`===`). Note that the types really must be the *exact* same, so `1e0 === 1` will not come out true because the one value is a `Num` and the other an `Int`.

The auto-coercion behavior of operators like `==` and `eq` can be really handy, but from a performance angle it can also be a trap. They coerce, use the result of the coercion for the comparison, and then throw it away. Repeatedly doing comparisons can thus repeatedly trigger coercions. If you have that situation, it makes sense to split the work into two phases: first "parse" the incoming data into the appropriate data types, and then go ahead and do the comparisons.

Finally, in any discussion on efficiency, it's worth noting that the runtime optimizer is good at lifting out duplicate type checks. Thus while in principle, if you read the built-ins source, `==` might seem cheaper in the case it gets two things have the same type because it isn't enforcing they are *precisely* the same type, in reality that extra check will get optimized out for `===` anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan Worthington. To clarify my question, I was trying to avoid the conversions. Thanks !!!